# set caretPosition to the right in a textField (javaFX)

Tags: javafx, textfield, caret

I am developing an javaFX application where the user has several textfields to fill and edit. I want that if you enter a new textfield by jumping from another by pressing TAB the content of the textfield is not selected and also the cursor is on the right. The textfields have an event listener that detects when they receive the focus and I have been testing various methods of the API to position the cursor and deselect content when entering the textfield, for the moment, all without success.

Where is my error?

```
id_ip2B_tf.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

        if (newValue) {
            // 1 - don't work
            id_ip2B_tf.deselect();
            id_ip2B_tf.positionCaret(id_ip2B_tf.getLength());

            // 2 - don't work
            id_ip2B_tf.end();                   
        }
    }
```

Comment: The [answer by Sai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55564441/6395627) should work for you, but unrelated to your question: Please learn Java naming conventions and stick to them—fields (when not static final), parameters, and local variables use `camelCase`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try wrapping the logic of setting the caret in Platform.runLater. Something like..

```
id_ip2B_tf.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            Platform.runLater(()->{
              id_ip2B_tf.deselect();
              id_ip2B_tf.positionCaret(id_ip2B_tf.getLength());
            });                   
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note you can simply do `Platform.runLater(id_ip2B_ft::end)`. The `end` method positions the caret after the last character and clears the selection.

Comment: @Slaw, Thank you for mentioning that. Not aware of that method till now.